# Como hacer múltiples insert mensuales en MySQL con Python para un sistema de facturación

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, mariadb

Tengo una base de datos en MariaDB para una agencia de arrendamientos con tables tales como: propietarios, arrendatarios, relacionIP, contratos, etc. Pero lo que ahora mismo lo que estoy necesitando es hacer registros que se inserten sólo una vez al mes de todos los arrendatarios en la tabla que guardará las facturas de cobro del arriendo.

Estas son algunas de las tablas con las que estoy trabajando:

**Tabla 'factura_arre' - Facturas de los arrendatarios**

```
+-----------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| fa_num    | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| c_cod     | int(11)    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| fa_fecha  | datetime   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| fa_iva    | float      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| fa_total  | float      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| fa_estado | tinyint(1) | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| fa_notas  | blob       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**Tabla 'configuracion': Contiene códigos y valores de impuestos:**

```
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| config_id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ivajuridico        | float        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**Tabla 'contratos': Relaciona la tabla relacionip con arrendatarios**

```
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| c_id          | int(11)      | NO   | UNI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| c_cod         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                |
| a_cc          | varchar(50)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| inquilino     | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| r_id          | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| c_fecha       | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**Tabla 'relacionip' - Relaciona la tabla inmuebles con propietarios:**

```
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| r_id      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| i_cod     | int(4)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| inmueble  | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| p_cc      | varchar(50)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| dueño     | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**Table 'inmuebles':**

```
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| i_id           | int(11)     | NO   | UNI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| i_cod          | int(4)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                |
| i_dir          | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| i_vlrenta      | float       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**Table 'arrendatarios':**

```
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| a_id            | int(11)      | NO   | UNI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| a_cc            | varchar(50)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                |
| a_nombres       | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| a_apellidos     | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| a_tpersona      | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| a_retefuente    | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| a_reteiva       | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| a_contribuyente | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

La razón por la que se debe realizar sólo una vez por me es para evitar posibles alteraciones. Lo que he tratado ha sido capturar primero el año/mes del sistema para luego compararlo con el de factura_arre, pero no me ha funcionado.

El código debería averiguar si los inquilinos son personas tipo 'jurídico' o 'natural' y luego agregar el valor correspondiente en la acción que inserta los demás datos solicitados de todos los arrendatarios con INSERT SELECT, pero lo que registra son el mismo valor de impuesto IVA y arriendo para todos los arrendatarios, tal como ven:

```
MariaDB> select * from factura_arre;
+--------+-------+---------------------+--------+----------+-----------+----------+
| fa_num | c_cod | fa_fecha            | fa_iva | fa_total | fa_estado | fa_notas |
+--------+-------+---------------------+--------+----------+-----------+----------+
|      9 |  1509 | 2017-05-27 13:49:34 |      0 |  1100000 |         0 | NULL     |
|     10 |  1526 | 2017-05-27 13:49:34 |      0 |  1100000 |         0 | NULL     |
|     11 |  1528 | 2017-05-27 13:49:34 |      0 |  1100000 |         0 | NULL     |
|     12 | 22736 | 2017-05-27 13:49:34 |      0 |  1100000 |         0 | NULL     |
|     13 | 22754 | 2017-05-27 13:49:34 |      0 |  1100000 |         0 | NULL     |
|     14 | 22789 | 2017-05-27 13:49:34 |      0 |  1100000 |         0 | NULL     |
+--------+-------+---------------------+--------+----------+-----------+----------+
```

El código completo Python que utilizo:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-
from Tkinter import*
from tkMessageBox import*
import MySQLdb
from controller import *
import analisis_arrendatarios
import os
import datetime
import time
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "")
#REPORTLAB PLATYPUS LIBRERY TO CREATE PDF FILE
from reportlab.platypus import (SimpleDocTemplate, PageBreak, Image, Spacer,
Paragraph, Table, TableStyle)
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.lib import colors
styleSheet = getSampleStyleSheet()
style = styleSheet['BodyText']

class Proceso_Fact_Auto_Arre(Frame):
        def __init__(self, parent, controller):
                Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        global opt

        #VARIABLES
        opt = IntVar()

        #WIDGETS
        header = Label(self, text="TENANTS AUTO BILLING PROCESS", font="bold")
        header.pack(pady=20, side=TOP)

        wrapper = Frame (self)
        wrapper.pack()

        r1 = Radiobutton(wrapper, text="Generate analysis", variable=opt, value=0).pack(pady=5, anchor=W)
        r2 = Radiobutton(wrapper, text="Generate billings", variable=opt, value=1).pack(pady=5, anchor=W)
        Button(wrapper, text="Start Process", bg='navy', foreground='white', activebackground='red3', activeforeground='white', command=operacion).pack(pady=5, anchor=W)

def operacion():
    if opt.get()==0:
        showinfo('Operación', "Generate Analysis")
        #Action to create and preview the PDF billing
    else:
        #SYSTEM YEAR/MONTH
        fechasys = time.strftime("%Y%m")
        #YEAR/MONTH FROM TENANT BILLING TABLE
        cursor.execute("SELECT EXTRACT( YEAR_MONTH FROM fa_fecha)FROM factura_arre;")
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        if fechasys == results:
            showerror("","This operation is not allowed for this month!")
        #if not fechasys == results:
        #showerror("","No records!")
        else:
            #showinfo('Operación', "Generate billings")
            cursor.execute("SELECT ivajuridico FROM configuracion;")
            dato1 = cursor.fetchall()
            for a in dato1:
                ivaj = a[0]
            cursor.execute("SELECT c_cod, now(), relacionip.i_cod, i_vlrenta, a_tpersona FROM contratos INNER JOIN relacionip ON contratos.r_id = relacionip.r_id INNER JOIN inmuebles ON relacionip.i_cod = inmuebles.i_cod INNER JOIN arrendatarios ON contratos.a_cc = arrendatarios.a_cc;")
            dato2 = cursor.fetchall()
            connect.commit()
            for i in dato2:
                if i[4] == 2:
                    #showinfo("","It's legal")
                    #iva = ivaj
                    iva = i[3]*ivaj/100
                else:
                    #showinfo("","It's natural")
                    iva = 0
                #total = i[3]*ivaj/100
                total = i[3]+iva
            cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO factura_arre(c_cod, fa_fecha, fa_iva, fa_total) 
                            SELECT c_cod, now(), '%f', '%f' FROM contratos 
                            INNER JOIN relacionip ON contratos.r_id = relacionip.r_id 
                            INNER JOIN inmuebles ON relacionip.i_cod = inmuebles.i_cod 
                            INNER JOIN arrendatarios ON contratos.a_cc = arrendatarios.a_cc;''' % (iva, total))
            connect.commit()
            showinfo('Operación', "Saved!")
```

Cuando ejecuto ese código en Python, este es el resultado en la tabla 'fatura_arre' de la base de datos:

```
mysql> select * from factura_Arre;
+--------+-------+---------------------+--------+----------+-----------+--------
--+
| fa_num | c_cod | fa_fecha            | fa_iva | fa_total | fa_estado | fa_nota
s |
+--------+-------+---------------------+--------+----------+-----------+--------
--+
|     40 |  1509 | 2017-06-08 01:16:01 |      0 |  1100000 |         0 | NULL
  |
|     41 |  1526 | 2017-06-08 01:16:01 |      0 |  1100000 |         0 | NULL
  |
|     42 |  1528 | 2017-06-08 01:16:01 |      0 |  1100000 |         0 | NULL
  |
|     43 | 22736 | 2017-06-08 01:16:01 |      0 |  1100000 |         0 | NULL
  |
|     44 | 22754 | 2017-06-08 01:16:01 |      0 |  1100000 |         0 | NULL
  |
|     45 | 22789 | 2017-06-08 01:16:01 |      0 |  1100000 |         0 | NULL
  |
|     46 | 22898 | 2017-06-08 01:16:01 |      0 |  1100000 |         0 | NULL
  |
|     47 | 22900 | 2017-06-08 01:16:01 |      0 |  1100000 |         0 | NULL
  |
+--------+-------+---------------------+--------+----------+-----------+--------
--+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con respecto al primer problema, que consiste en impedir que se inserten datos más de una vez al mes en la tabla 'factura_arre', la solución es la siguiente:

```
#AÑO/MES DEL SISTEMA
fechasys = time.strftime("%Y%m")
#AÑO/MES DE MYSQL FACTURA
cursor.execute("SELECT EXTRACT( YEAR_MONTH FROM fa_fecha)FROM factura_arre;")
results = cursor.fetchall()
for fechasys in results:
        showerror("","No se permite esta operación por este mes!")
        break
```